# How big does a buoy have to be to float a person?

Tags: buoyancy

I am trying to understand more about buoys. 
How big does a buoy have to be to float a person who weighs
20kg?40kg?

Please explain and provide formula. 
Thank you

Comment: As big a [life jacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_flotation_device), I would think.

Comment: Some people have enough body fat to float without any help from an artificial buoy.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Archimedies' Principle. Archimedies' Principle states that you have to displace an amount of water that equals to the weight of the thing you're trying to float. Find out how much the total system weighs(mass of man + mass of buoy), then divide by the density of water to get the volume of water you need to displace such that your buoy floats.  Do note that the volume of your buoy + person must be smaller than the water displaced.

The formula you will need is just density = mass/volume.